# How to loop through a list of tables by their corresponding name?

Tags: mysql, sql, machform

I want to loop over a list of tables that I get using the following query.

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
where (lower(table_name) like '%ap_form_%') &&  substring(table_name, 9, char_length(table_name) - 1) in (
    select form_id
    from ap_form_elements elements
    where elements.element_type = "email"
);
```

This query gets all the table names of the tables that have got an email field.  I need to use this list to access the actual tables, and for each table append their `date_created` field to a temporal table variable.

How can I access these tables? I know their name but I don't know how to get the actual tables and loop through them.

Comment: You have a query that queried meta data (i.e. data that the DBMS uses to manage its data). Now you want to have a query that queries your database. These are two distinct things that cannot be done together. So run your query and use the result to build the final query (either manually or with a programming language). Then run the built query. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That could work.. I was hoping I could simply do it in MySQL. I'll try building the queries in Python then. Thanks.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Also, it does answer my question.